# Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know how to find whether a function is linear transformation or not when $L: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ but how to do it when $L: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n+1}$?

For Example:

$$L:\pmatrix{u_1 & u_2} \to \pmatrix{u_1+6 & u_1 & u_1+u_2}$$

Comment: The definition doesn't depend on the dimension of the domain and codomain. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_linear_map Thus, if you can do it in one case, you should proceed in the same way for any other case.

Comment: @Max I wasn't sure what you meant on the last line so make sure it is still correct (if it is, this isn't actually a linear transformation -- it's an *affine* transformation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U,V$ be vector spaces over some field $\mathbb{F}$ a homomorphism or linear map is a function $f:U \rightarrow V$ such that the following two properties hold:

$i) ~f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ for all $u,v \in U$.

$ii) ~f(\lambda u)=\lambda f(u)$ for all $u \in U, \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$.

Now it makes no difference what $U,V$ are and in particular is doesn't matter if $\dim(U) \neq \dim(V)$ so you can just go ahead and prove a map is linear in this case you have as you would in any other case. By simply showing $i,ii$ hold.

So for the first condition in relation to your question take $2$ vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and add them then apply the transformation to them is this the same as applying the transformation to both vectors separately? (It is), show this.

Same kind of ideas for the second condition.